# Android Studio emulator Keyboard is showing obscure letter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

The emulator was working fine. I tested the Text Field several time to check new Task and update them. Suddenly the keyboard seems weird. I restarted the application, but couldn't solve it.

I need to know if it is hardware problem or Emulator system problem? Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Here is the code

```
Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: TextField(
          controller: _postController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Enter your thoughts',
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.edit),
          ),
        ),
      ),
   
      SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_postController.text.isNotEmpty) {
              NoteData.post.add(_postController.text);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.